# Neo4j BatchInserter slow shutdown

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-batch-inserter

I'm using Neo4j's BatchInserter to insert a varying number of Relationships in a large graph (500million+ Nodes)

It is exceptionally fast, inserting many 1000's of Relationships per minute.

But the shutdown is very slow, taking over an hour, even if only a small number of Relationships were inserted.

Looking inside `org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.shutdown()`, I see that there are a number of operations which it does, including `repopulateAllIndexes()`

I don't know which part of the shutdown is taking so long, but if I know for a fact that the new Relationships do not affect any indexes, is it worth it to subclass `BatchInserterImpl` and skip some of these shutdown operations?

Comment: There's a lot of flushing to disk going on as well in that phase. I suggest you  attach a profiler to the process (e.g. YourKit) and see where time is actually spent.

Answer (score 0):

Right, the BatchInserter doesn't go through great lengths to optimize the shutdown process w/ regards to only rebuilding affected indexes. There's one boolean controlling this and it's simply whether or not any labels have been changed on any node. If so then a full rebuild of the indexes (off of one store scan) is triggered. This can probably be improved, as you mention.